# GAE Push notifications

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm still at the level of experimenting with GAE and I was wondering if it's possible for GAE to somehow keep the socket open for indefinite period of time, or perhaps generate some kind of push messages. I want to write a desktop application that will communicate with the backend running on GAE and every once in a while display some notifications if some get generated by the backend, but I don't quite like the idea of polling the server every few seconds.
Any ideas?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/channel/

Comment: Thank you very much good sir :) channels, huh? I knew it would have some fancy name that I would never be able to guess :P

Comment: np. There are limits on sockets in GAE that require the use of such tools.

Comment: @PaulCollingwood, perhaps expand this into an answer...?

Comment: @PaulCollingwood: Channel API is javascript-based web-only API that can not be used for desktop apps.

Answer (score 1):

A few notes on existing APIs and why they would not work for a native desktop app:

1. [Channels API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/channel/) is a javascript-based browser-only solution, so it would not work for a native desktop app.
2. [XMPP API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/xmpp/) allows your GAE app to function as a XMPP client: sending and receiving messages. It does not act as a server and has no facilities for external clients to connect to it (requires external XMPP server to do so).
3. [Sockets API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/sockets/) is outbound-only. It does not allow you to open listening sockets needed for long-running server-to-client push.
4. Outbound Sockets, where server connects to client: most clients are behind [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation), so even if tempting, server-to-client socket connections can not practically be established. Even if you are willing to delve into the world of [STUN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STUN), GAE limits number of threads needed to service sockets (select-based NIO is not available).

Running server-to-client async push is not possible on normal GAE instances. There are however two practical approaches:

1. Use external services: depending on number of connections, this might be the cheapest (in terms of time & cost) solution. See [Pusher](https://pusher.com/), [PubNub](http://www.pubnub.com/), etc..
2. Use [Managed VMs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/managed-vms/). They run the full JVM (or Python, Go, Node.js), so do not have above limitations. You can run any existing pub/sub server.